# Keep intermediate DataFrame computations using dask

Tags: python, dask

Is there a way to instruct dask to keep intermediate values when performing expensive computations?

In the example below, I would like dask to preserve the intermediate column `d['c']` created when calculating `d['d']`.

```
## very large file
d = ddf.read_csv("F:/tmp.csv")

d['c'] = d['a'] * d['b']

d['d'] = d['c'] + 1


## first call
%timeit d['d'].value_counts().compute()

## second call takes roughly the same time
%timeit d['d'].value_counts().compute()
```

Yet in my experiments, it seems to be calculating `d['c']` each time. Is there a way to tell dask to keep `d['c']` hanging around somewhere? What is the best practice for this kind of worklow? I plan on creating a lot of intermediate columns to use in many subsequent computations and don't want to calculate them from scratch each time. Or is my understanding completely wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Call multiple results at the same time

You can call compute on many things at the same time to share intermediate results

```
dask.compute(d.min(), d.max())
```

#### Use persist to keep data in memory

You can use the `.persist()` method or the `dask.persist(...)` function to compute results, but keep them as dask collections

```
d['c'] = d['a'] * d['b']
d['d'] = (d['c'] + 1).persist()
```

or

```
d['c'] = d['a'] * d['b']
d['d'] = d['c'] + 1
d = d.persist()
```

#### Opportunistic caching

If you are using the first-generation single-machine scheduler then you can use opportunistic caching. See http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/caching.html for more information.